# WixIISExtension.dll could not be added

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wix

For some reason visual studio 2008 says I can't add this wix extension. I have installed wix3.7 and tried repairing the installation.

[image]

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the root issue is that Visual Studio 2008 is running on NETFX 2.0 and the extensions were incorrectly compiled against the NETFX 4.0. I believe this issue was fixed in WiX v3.8.

Comment: Since it is not a stable release, is it worth to use? :P

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this is blocked from working, but I believe a work around is to add the reference manually via editing the XML project file.  You can do that in visual studio by right clicking on the project and unloading it first. I had a similar issue and once the reference was added manually it showed in solution explorer and built fine. Let me know if you need details on the unloading of the wixproj file and specifics on updating the XML.